# Show response from ajax error function in django template

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

A part of the django view which is executed is as follows:

```
def traxio_advice(request):
     .......
     .......
     elif calculation['statusCode'] == 400:
         response = JsonResponse({'message': 'The calculation is not available! Please try another mileage.'}, status=500)
         return response
```

And in django template I have ajax call as follows :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '{% url 'traxio_advice' %}',
    data: {
        firstname: $('input[name=firstname]').val(),
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
    },
    success: function (data) {
        ......
    },
    error: function (data) {
         var message = $.parseJSON(data.responseText).message;
         $('#calculation-error').removeClass('hidden').html(message)
    },
    beforeSend: function () {
         $('#result-content').html('<div class="loader"></div>');
    }
})
```

The problem is in the error function. I get what I want, thus, the data is correct.

```
message = "The calculation is not available! Please try another mileage."
```

But the message isn't showing in the div with the id `calculation-error`.

Instead I see the loader from the `beforeSend` function on the screen and in the console I get

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/master/traxio_advice/ 400 (Bad Request)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: you originally asked a question where you have set the status to be 500 so I answerd. Now you have changed your code to show status to 400 that's not on

Comment: If your server is really having an internal server error (when you set the status code to 400) post a full stactrace

Comment: @e4c5 I wrote the comment that it was a mistake.

Comment: Your code is running into 500 Internal Server Error, first check if response is returned properly or not

Comment: @AjayGupta My bad. I updated my question. That is the error that I get.

Comment: @Boky Again, your request is not returning anything in response, you sure that post request is accepted in your view?

Comment: @AjayGupta If I `print(response)` I get `<JsonResponse status_code=400, "application/json">`. Thus, I think that the post request is accepted.

Comment: @Boky Exactly, your view is only returning a response based on built-in Bad Request module. You are not the one handling this response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136849/discussion-between-boky-and-ajay-gupta).

Comment: Can you show us your template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Just for the info, If anyone else would have a similar problem.***

Actually the problem was in the `beforeSend` function and the template .

The div with id `#calculation-error` (where I wanted to show the error) was inside the div with id `#result-content`.

But in the beforeSend function I replaced the content of the div with the id `#result-content`.

Thus in the template like this :

```
<div id="result-content">
     <div class="loader"></div>
</div>
```

I tried to show error in the div with the id `#calculation-error`. It couldn't be shown because that div doesn't exist.